Is this action really avoiding SOH Issues?
I am learning C# with a renderer program.
V3 _pixel00 = ...; //V3 is a Vector class
V3 _stepU = ...;
V3 _stepV = ...;
double x, y = ...;

...

var pointOnScreen = _pixel00 + _stepU * (x + sS.X) + _stepV * (y + sS.Y);

When I ran my code, VS told me in the last line, 5,000 MB allocated in SOH, 4 issues.
So I write the following weird function:
public static V3 HorribleFunction(ref V3 a, ref V3 b, ref V3 c, double rateA, double rateB, double rateC)
  {
     return new V3(a.X * rateA + b.X * rateB + c.X * rateC,
                   a.Y * rateA + b.Y * rateB + c.Y * rateC,
                   a.Z * rateA + b.Z * rateB + c.Z * rateC);
  }

var pointOnScreen = HorribleFunction(ref _pixel00, ref _stepU, ref _stepV, 1, x + sS.X, y + sS.Y);

Then the warning is gone. My question is, is the issue really solved by using ref on all the objects? Or I just fool the compiler/plug-in?
update
here is the code of operators.
public static V3 operator +(V3 a, V3 b)
{
    return new (a.X + b.X, a.Y + b.Y, a.Z + b.Z);
}

public static V3 operator *(V3 a, double b)
{
    return new V3(a.X * b,a.Y * b, a.Z * b);
}

Thanks.

Is V3 a class or struct?

@gunr2171 V3 is a class.

Is "5,000 MB allocated in SOH, 4 issues." exception text? What was the exception? That seems like a rather cryptic message; I've never seen anything refer to SOH (I'm guessing it's the Small Object Heap - aka "the heap"). You'll need to look at how operator + is defined on you V3 type (oh, and what that * invokes as well)

@Flydog57 It comes from "Dynamic Program Analysis", I am not sure it's a built-in plug-in of VS or it from ReSharper. I did the same thing in operator + and operator *, it just calculate the coordinate in each dimensions.  C# doesn't allow to use ref in operator functions, So I don't know what you mean here.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Dynamic_Program_Analysis.html#turning-dpa-off

@HansPassant Shut it down can't improve any performance, right? XD


My question is, is the issue really solved by using ref on all the objects? Or I just fool the compiler/plug-in?

Don't be silly, what "solved" (or rather, improved) your problem is the fact that you're no longer calling your user-defined operators that allocate a new object every time, and instead you do the math yourself. In fact, if you remove the ref from your "horrible" function, you'd get exactly the same result, memory-wise (and a performance boost to boot).
To actually solve your problem, you need to stop abusing reference types and use value types for whatever V3 is. And if it's a vector, then don't roll your own, use the built-in Vector3. You will absolutely not reach even 10% of its performance, especially with code like that.

Thanks for the answer. As I said, I am just learning language. So would you mind to show how to wisely overwrite a operator function?  The tutorial of Microsoft also create a new object.

I did, use a value type. And I also mentioned not to write your own, you won’t be able to write anything usable yourself.
